# Cordova Plugin - Java: wait for callback

Tags: java, synchronization, cordova-plugins

I have a plugin method that acts on remote hardware via Bluetooth.
It sends a command to the hardware, which executes some action.
After the hardware action finishes a callback defined outside of my method is called.

I only want to call `CallbackContext.success(...)` or `CallbackContext.error(...)` after the callback is called, so i want to wait for my callback to be called.

How would i go about this?

E.g. part of `CordovaPlugin`-class:

```
public void actOnHardware(CallbackContext callbackContext)
{
    this.verifiyBluetoothEnabled();

    this.hardwareConnection.doSomething()

    // Now wait for the callback to complete before calling 
    // callbackContext.success() or error()

    callbackContext.error("Not implemented.");
}

@Override
public void hardwareActionCallback(result)
{
  // Notify actOnHardware() that we're finished.
}
```

This seems to be more of a Java thing, but i can't get my head to wrap around it.

Is using `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()` a viable option or does calling `wait()` prevent the callback from getting called due to thread stuff? If so - how to solve this?

E.g. is it sufficient to just do:

```
private Object lockObj;
private boolean actionFinished;

public void actOnHardware(CallbackContext callbackContext)
{
    this.verifiyBluetoothEnabled();

    this.actionFinished = false;

    this.hardwareConnection.doSomething()

    while(!this.actionFinished)
        this.lockObj.wait();

    callbackContext.error("Not implemented.");
}

@Override
public void hardwareActionCallback(result)
{
  this.actionFinished = true;
  this.lockObj.notify();
}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: Hi did you solved this?